# QGIS point layer creation

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I used this to create line layer in the QGIS console:

```
iface.addVectorLayer("LineString", "pointlayer", "memory")
```

If I need a point layer what do i need to use?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe :

```
iface.addVectorLayer("Point", "pointlayer", "memory")
```

But it's an hard question...